# Switching debuggers

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I use Visual Studio C++ 97 for a project for my a employer. Yesterday I installed VS SDK 2008 for another project. Now, when I try to debug on 97 uses the newly installed debugger. Is there a way to switch with the original debugger? (the compiler has no problems)

Thanks,
Sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do it on SDK 97 by pressing Tools -> Options -> Debug and enabling 'Just-In-Time debugging' option.

Comment: @ckv: You should not edit your own question to include the *answer*. It's preferred to maintain a clear distinction between questions and answers. Posting an answer as was done here is the appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to debug the program in VS 2008. What you need to do is run the program and then open VS 2008 and attach your application. Then you can put breakpoints and debug.

Comment: No, I need to debug with the original debugger (97) though the application is by default attached with the newer version.

Comment: Why dont you press F5 from the original debugger (97) after opening the solution in it.

Comment: I can do it some times but not all of the times. There are times that an executab;es needsdata from another executable. I have found the solution. I am answering my question.